# Avoid too many "declare same elements of Rcpp List" in nested loops

Tags: c++, r, loops, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I would like to ask about how to save computational time about accessing List in nested loop. Here is an Rcpp example including two functions:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void first(const Rcpp::List ETA
          ,const int N
          ,const int I
                      ) {   
    for(int i = 0; i < I; ++i) {
        arma::rowvec eta = ETA[i];
        for(int n = 0; n < N; ++n) {
            // use eta to do some calculation
        }
    }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void second(const Rcpp::List ETA
           ,const int N
           ,const int I
                      ) {   
    for(int n = 0; n < N; ++n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < I; ++i) {
            arma::rowvec eta = ETA[i];
            // use eta to do some calculation
        }
    }
}
```

Compare the time in R:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("test.cpp") # save the above code as "test.cpp"
ETA = list()
N = 10^8
I = 10
for (i in 1:I) ETA[[i]] = rep(0,i) # just an example.
ptm <- proc.time(); first(ETA,N,I); print((proc.time() - ptm))
#    user  system elapsed 
#       0       0       0 
ptm <- proc.time(); second(ETA,N,I); print((proc.time() - ptm))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   16.69    0.00   16.69
```

Here the `ETA` is a list whose each element can either have dynamic length (vector) or dynamic dimension (matrix). In this code, the first way is much faster than the second way. But for practical needs, the second way can reduce computational time when there are other variables iterated over `n`.

Questions:

For either first way or second way, can we declare the `eta` outside (before) the loops so that we don't need to declare the same `eta` so many times?

Comment: I don't have time to work through your code line by line -- but that said how do we know it's not just a random programming error?  It's not quite a _minimal_ reproducible verfiable example. Any chance you could distill it some more?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Hi, I've tried to simplify the example (see above). I compared the two functions. The second way declares `eta` much more times than the first one. Can I declare the `eta` before the two loops, so I don't need declare the same `eta` in the loops to save time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing an implicit conversion and a deep copy during every loop, so it's no surprise that the compiler can't optimize that away.

What you can do is pre-calculate all the etas and store them in a vector. (I filled in some work within the loop, since empty loops can be optimized out completely).

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double third(const Rcpp::List ETA
              ,const int N
              ,const int I) {   
  double output=0;
  
  // pre-create eta rowvecs
  std::vector<arma::rowvec> eta_vec(Rf_xlength(ETA));
  for(int i = 0; i < I; ++i) {
    eta_vec[i] = arma::rowvec(Rcpp::NumericVector(ETA[i]));
  }
  
  for(int n = 0; n < N; ++n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < I; ++i) {
      output += sum(eta_vec[i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Results:

```
> ptm <- proc.time(); first(ETA,N,I); print((proc.time() - ptm))
[1] 0
   user  system elapsed 
  2.761   0.000   2.761 
> #    user  system elapsed 
> #       0       0       0 
> ptm <- proc.time(); second(ETA,N,I); print((proc.time() - ptm))
[1] 0
   user  system elapsed 
 29.935   0.000  29.930 
> 
> ptm <- proc.time(); third(ETA,N,I); print((proc.time() - ptm))
[1] 0
   user  system elapsed 
  2.599   0.000   2.598
```

Comment: Nice work! I wonder what if `ETA[[i]]` is a matrix, for example, `for (i in 1:I) ETA[[i]] = matrix(0,i,i)`. How can I modify your code?

Comment: Check this answer for explicit conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57516726/converting-r-matrix-to-armamat-with-list. You can set a temporary NumericMatrix if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I prefer to extend your method. Is it possible to extend your method for matrix?

Comment: The link shows you how to do it, there are several ways. E.g.: `eta_vec[i] = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(ETA[i]);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now accepted. :)